# IDE with C and embedded Javascript support

Tags: javascript, c, windows, ide, editor

I have a 100k line C project with about 30k lines worth of embedded Mozilla Spidermonkey Javascript used for scripting GUI.

What is the best way to edit C and Javascript together or at least have a reasonable editor for the Javascript?

On Linux, I used to use two different instances of Eclipse one configured for C, one for Javascript. IT was not a particularly convenient solution.

Now that I am working on a Windows build, Visual Studio 2008 is doing fine with C support but Javascript support seems a bit ...lacking.

**All I really want is to jump quickly between functions in the Javascript code and inspect variables.** There are about 30 .js files. I can live without code completion and other niceties.

Ideally, I would see when calls to C code are made and jump to the C code but that is probably asking too much.

Otherwise it seems I am back to Notepad++ and grep.

Comment: vs2010 ought to do that for you. Or even better, vs11 (rc). Or you could try my favorite (never tried it for C though); sublime text 2.

Comment: I checked out sublime text 2 and it sure looks nice! It also makes it very convenient to search for occurrences across multiple files. However, you can tell that is has no knowledge that those are .js files besides syntax highlighting. No way to jump to function definition specifically.

Comment: Yes there is. Use Ctrl+P and then type `@` in the window that appears. Everything you types after will be symbols in the file you're currently in. And you can do something even better. Say you have a file named (and placed) at `aba/cdc/efe/my.js` and it has a function named `do_stuff()`, you can hit control+p and type `acem@stuff` and it will find the function for you (no matter what file you started in).

Comment: Thanks Alxandr! Function search within a single file works splendidly! However, how would I look for a function in a different file in the same directory? Say, I have function foo in main.js that calls bar, and I would like to jump to the definition of this bar function, which could be in any of the 30 .js files. Ctrl+Shft+F gives general matches across open files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [Zeus editor](http://www.zeusedit.com) and it has a automatic ctags feature that works well for C, letting you jump between things like functions and structures etc.

I have not used the editor for JavaScript but the [ctags web page](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html) lists JavaScript as one of the support languages so it might work.